# How would you complete a completion bar in Android?

Tags: android-layout, android

In my Android app, I would like there to be a bar indicating how much of a project a user has completed.

I would call it a Progress Bar, but unlike what most people call a Progress Bar, it doesn't indicate a computer's progress in a certain processing task, but indicates over a long period of time how far a user has gotten.

I used a simple approach when I only allowed 3 tasks per project. I simple saved separate images of what the bar looked like at each stage. However, with projects having many dozens of tasks, this simply isn't realistic. There must be a better way.

I've mocked up a simple example of what I am trying to do. I'd appreciate any help and advice

[image: Completion Bar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ProgressBar. Its official documentation contains sample code http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

```
    <ProgressBar
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:minHeight="20dip"
        android:maxHeight="20dip"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        />
```

Comment: But according to Android Studio, ProgressBar is a spinning thing, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. I edited my answer to show layout code for a horizontal bar.

Comment: This solution saved much of my time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any difference between what you are trying to achieve and the normal functionality of a progress bar. You just need to assign a value to each of your tasks, like if a task has 12 subtasks and each subtask has a weight of one, you should set the max value of the progress bar as 12 and increment it each time a user completes his subtask.

The normal progress bar was made for this exact problem. So that you dont have to make images/resources for each different task. Do let me know if this makes sense to you or if you need help with your code. I'll be more than happy to do so.